# How to Remove Old Events from the Managing Events Tab

Tags: civievent

I have eight events under my "Manage Events" Tab on Civi. Three of them are upcoming, but five of them are left over from 2012. When I try to put an end date to the event, so they will be cleared from my this page, but not deleted, I am given this error blocking message:

"Sorry an error occurred
We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.

Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.

Error type: Could not find a valid session key."

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely misleading. You'll find more details in your CiviCRM error log (and/or perhaps your CMS error log). The CiviCRM Log Viewer extension is the simplest way to see those.

It's likely that these old events have some configuration that is blowing up when you resave them with the end date.

Since you just want to hide them, your simplest course of action is to set an end date directly using sql, e.g. with something like:

```
UPDATE civicrm_event SET end_date = start_date where isnull(end_date) and start_date < '2013-01-01'
```

Comment: Where can I find the "The CiviCRM Log Viewer extension" on Civi? Furthermore, where do I go to edit events using sql?

Comment: You can enable the extension directly via the extensions menu, assuming your site is setup to allow it. https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/
Using direct sql on your database isn't an option with the CiviCRM UI but usually is an option from your host (typically using phpmyadmin, but there are other possibilities as well).